# SSH How to ignore checking IdentityFile?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have setup a config file located at "~/.ssh/config" which contains some IdentityFile lines to point to the key files that I use for some of my servers.

> e.g. IdentityFile ~/Data/Keys/KeyFile.pem

This works fine when I want to connect to my servers on ec2 which require a key file for authentication.

When I want to connect to a server that does not use a key file and requires a password ssh tries to use my key files in ~/.ssh/config and the connection fails with:

> Received disconnect from host.ip: 2: Too many authentication failures for root

Is there a ssh command argument that I can use to connect to this server so that ssh does not try to use my identity files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to limit the use of the `IdentityFile` lines to your EC2 host with the `host` statement:

```
Host YourEC2host.com 
    IdentityFile ~/Data/Keys/KeyFile.pem
```

For more information, see the section about the host section in the `ssh_config` man page.